# How can I search for different types of issues in a wide range of components using a JQL filter?

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to search for different types of issues such as `bug` and `request` in different components using JQL. My current JQL is similar to the following:

`project = 1234 AND type = Bug AND status != Closed AND component in ("Product - A", "Product - B", "Product - C, "Product - D", "Product - E", "Product - O", "Product - P", "Product - H", "Product - R")`

However, I want to search for types which are both BUGS and REQUESTS.

Answer (score 0):

An issue in Jira can only be one type. So if you look for both type = Bug AND type is Request you never find any issues.

If you want to filter for either bug or request you can do

```
type = Bug OR type = Request
```

Hope this helps